# Uploading image in database in MVC 4

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This action method is uploading the image, when it executes  dbx.SaveChanges(); method then it throws the exception.
 "String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated"

```
    public ActionResult FileUpload(int id, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        dbCRMEntities dbx = new dbCRMEntities();
        CONTACT con = new CONTACT();
        if (file != null)
        {
            string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                                   Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images"), pic);
            // file is uploaded
            file.SaveAs(path);
            //con.NAME = path;
            con = dbx.CONTACTS.FirstOrDefault(Id => id == Id.CONTACT_ID);
            con.IMAGE = path;
            dbx.SaveChanges();

        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Here image is type of string for storing the path. Please guide what changes should I make?

Comment: check data type and size of table in the database

Comment: Image is saved in /Content/Images folder,but it's not saving "path" in database,in db IMAGE is of type varchar(50)

Comment: calculate lenth of path variable , I think it is greater than 50

Comment: possible duplicate of [String or binary data would be truncated when uploading file in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16469042/string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-when-uploading-file-in-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

That generally happens when try to insert wrong datatyp/data length into some column of sql table. e.g: if your column is varchar[100] and you are trying to insert longer paragraphs. check the values and respective table columns carefully, the error lies somewhere there

Comment: yes it was only data length problem, I make it varchar(100) and its working now, thanks Kumar Manish